# Converting a type void to System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I'm having a conversion error I would like some help in overcoming.

At the moment I am trying to take a screen capture of my desktop and store it in a variable I can pass around. Right now, this code looks like this:

```
ScreenCapture capture = new ScreenCapture();
Image capturedImageObj=  capture.CaptureImage(showCursor, curSize, curPosition, startPoint, Point.Empty, bounds, _screenPath, fi);
```

However, by doing that I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Drawing.Image'

So, I tried to type cast the capture.CaptureImage and it generated the same error. The line I wrote was thus:

```
Image capturedImageObj=  (Image)capture.CaptureImage(showCursor, curSize, curPosition, startPoint, Point.Empty, bounds, _screenPath, fi);
```

My CaptureImage method is the following:

```
  public void CaptureImage(bool showCursor, Size curSize, Point curPos, Point SourcePoint, Point DestinationPoint, Rectangle SelectionRectangle, string FilePath, string extension)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(SourcePoint, DestinationPoint, SelectionRectangle.Size);

            if (showCursor)
            {
                Rectangle cursorBounds = new Rectangle(curPos, curSize);
                Cursors.Default.Draw(g, cursorBounds);
            }
        }

        if (saveToClipboard)
        {
            Image img = (Image)bitmap;

            if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;

            ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(img);
            OnUpdateStatus(this, args);

        }
```

So, seeing that I have set the method to be void, I changed it so that it would require an image like so:

```
  public Image CaptureImage(bool showCursor, Size curSize, Point curPos, Point SourcePoint, Point DestinationPoint, Rectangle SelectionRectangle, string FilePath, string extension)
```

But then it generated the following error:

> An object of a type convertible to 'System.Drawing.Image' is required.

This error points to the following chunk of code with the second if statement being the culprit:

```
  if (saveToClipboard)
  {
     Image img = (Image)bitmap;

     if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;

     ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(img);
     OnUpdateStatus(this, args);
 }
```

I've ran out of ideas on how to beat these errors. Can anyone please shed some light / new insight so that I can get rid of them?

Comment: For future reference, all though it is generally good to show the things you have tried. In this example, you make the question a bit confusing by showing each change to your code. It would have been better to just show your current code, the line that errors, and the error message... then again, Googling the error message should have solved your problem anyway

Comment: Just wanted to give a detailed overview to what I've tried and avoid down voting. Didn't work :(

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, and I understand you were just trying to provide as much information as possible. It's just in this instance you have perhaps confused things a bit by having too many code changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CaptureImage` requires an `Image` returned but you return `void/nothing` in the `if (OnUpdateStatus == null)`. Even you return some image there, you still have to return the image outside that `if` block, otherwise it may complain that `Not all code paths return a value`.

```
 public Image CaptureImage(bool showCursor, Size curSize, Point curPos, Point SourcePoint, Point DestinationPoint, Rectangle SelectionRectangle, string FilePath, string extension)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(SourcePoint, DestinationPoint, SelectionRectangle.Size);

        if (showCursor)
        {
            Rectangle cursorBounds = new Rectangle(curPos, curSize);
            Cursors.Default.Draw(g, cursorBounds);
        }
    }

    if (saveToClipboard)
    {
        Image img = (Image)bitmap;

        if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return bitmap;//<--- here

        ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(img);
        OnUpdateStatus(this, args);

    }
    return bitmap;//<--- and here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

because your method

```
public Image CaptureImage(
```

expects a return type of image that you are not returning. There are 2 points of return in your code.

Point 1:

```
if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;
```

gives error because as your return type needs to be image and you are not returning that so you should do it like

```
if (OnUpdateStatus == null) 
     return null; //or a valid image
```

and before exiting the method you need to return image as well

```
return someImage; //as the last line in your method before closing brackets
```

Comment: @musefan StackExchange isn't a place for ego. Please be more productive with your comments like pointing out what makes the answer crappy.

Comment: @Romoku: The comment box won't hold enough characters for me to copy and paste the question. If NoOne reads the question fully, then they would know what the problem is. And I don't think "ego" is a relevant accusation in this context...

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually return an Image from your CaptureImage method. Your return statement isn't returning anything.